# How to read all contents of file, including NUL chars between valid text?

Tags: c

I have a file that I need to read into a buffer (char *) but the problem is that the file has some "funny characters" in it inbetween the valid text.

[image]

So when I write some code like the following:

```
  FILE *fp;
  if((fp = fopen(".\\test.txt", "rt"))==NULL){
    printf("Cannot open file2\n");
  }

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  long int fsize = ftell(fp);
  rewind(fp);
  //char *buffer2 = malloc(fsize * sizeof(char));
  buffer = malloc(fsize * sizeof(char));
  fread(buffer, 1, fsize, fp);
  buffer[fsize] = '\0';
  fclose(fp); 

  printf("fsize = %i\n", fsize);
  printf("Buffer = %s\n", buffer);
```

It only prints out the first part of the text file like follows:

Buffer = header

And obviously stops at the first NUL char.

Is thier any way to read the entire buffer of the file, including funny chars?

Or is this not possible in C?

The FSIZE is read correctly, just the FREAD does not read the entire buffer ;-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Thanks

Lynton

UPDATE: OK, I was being a little stupid.....if I write the buffer to a file it has everything in it, only if I write it out to the screen does it stop at the null so that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the file in "text" mode ("rt"), use binary mode instead ("rb").

Also, it might well be reading the data, but the `printf("Buffer = %s\n", buffer)` will only print up to the first NUL, so your debug is not going to do what your want.  You probably want to write a little hex dumping function.

Answer (score 0):

> How to read all contents of file, including NUL chars between valid text?

Errors:

1. Allocate enough space if attempting to make a *string*.  OP's code is 1 short.  This is a dubious goal if data read may include *null chracters*.
2. Open in binary mode [@Lawrence Dol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5415198/2410359)
3. Some more error checking is useful.

---

```
// FILE *fp = fopen(".\\test.txt", "rt");
FILE *fp = fopen(".\\test.txt", "rb");
if (fp==NULL) {
  printf("Cannot open file2\n");
  exit(-1);
}

if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
  printf("fseek() trouble\n");
  exit(-1);
}
long fsize = ftell(fp);
if (fsize == -1 || fsize >= SIZE_MAX) {
  printf("fell() trouble\n");
  exit(-1);
}
// Add 1 if trying to make a string.
size_t sz = (size_t) fsize;
if (making_a_string) sz++;

rewind(fp);
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * sz);
if (buffer == NULL && sz > 0) {  // Tolerate a file size of 0
  printf("malloc() trouble\n");
  exit(-1);
}          

size_t in = fread(buffer, 1, fsize, fp);
fclose(fp); 
if (in != fsize) {
  printf("fread() trouble\n");
  exit(-1);
}          
if (making_a_string) {
  buffer[fsize] = '\0';
}
```

---

To print the entire data, use, `fwrite()`.  In order to print a character array, a trailing *null chracter* is not needed as in a *string*, but the length of the character array is used.

```
 printf("fsize = %ld\n", fsize);  // Note: %ld
 printf("Buffer = <", );
 fwrite(buffer, 1, fsize, stdout);
 printf(">\n");
```